# Cannot create Vue.js Carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I try to create a Vue.js Carousel as a component.
However, I'm lost.

It should change to the next "slider" every 5 seconds, with image 
and the text. Or if you can, then please put a link in the description.

friendly regard

P.S I'm novice.

```js
<template>
  <div >
    <div class="carousel"
      v-for="(item,i) in items"
      :key="i"
      :src="item.source"
      :alt="item.alt"
      transition="fade"
    >
     <div class="carousel-image">
        <img v-attr="item.src" alt="image">

     </div>
     <div class="carousel-text">
        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
        <p>{{item.position}}</p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            source: '../assets/companies/migros.svg.png',
            title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
            alt: "1",
            position: "Jon Doe, -- Migros Chef "
          },
          {
            source: '../assets/companies/xxx.svg.png',
            title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
            alt: "2",
            position: "Jon Doe, -- xxx "
          },
   
         
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

give you an example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
   list: [1,2,3,4],
   curIndex: 0
  }
 },
 created () {
  window.setInterval(_=>{
   if(this.curIndex+1>this.list.length-1){
    this.curIndex = 0;
   }else{
    this.curIndex++
   }
  },3000)
 }
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
 }
 .wrapper>div{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px; 
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff; 
 }
 .wrapper>div:nth-child(1){
  background: red;
 }
 .wrapper>div:nth-child(2){
  background: blue;
 }
 .wrapper>div:nth-child(3){
  background: orange;
 }
 .wrapper>div:nth-child(4){
  background: yellow;
 }
 .fade-enter,.fade-leave-active{
  opacity: 0;
 }
 .fade-enter-active,.fade-leave-active{
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <transition-group tag="div" class="wrapper" name="fade">
    <div v-for="(item,index) of list" :key="index" v-show="index==curIndex">
   {{item}}
  </div>
 </transition-group>
</div>
```

Comment: but what if I want to have text on the side, which would also change?

Comment: use v-for to render your items and use transition-group to deal with transitions,it's the same as my example